# Receiving 500 internal server error even though I receive data from LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, https, entity-framework-6

StackOverflow.

The issue I am having today is when I send a get request to localhost:xxxxx trying to obtain a singular food item by ID, I receive a 500 internal server error.

What I do not understand about this is, I went through the code in debugging and it shows that it finds the item from my database with all the information it needs, but when it is sending it in a "OK(food)", I receive a 500 internal service error even though it has the information.

I am pretty new to web api, so some explanation would be appreciated. I am using Visual Studio 2015, Entity Frame Work 6, and a SQL Management Server DB.

**I am sorry for posting links, it says I need 10 reputation to post images**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63591/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/foods/" + Request.QueryString["ID"]).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string foodstring = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Food editFood = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Food>(foodstring);
                EditFoodName.Text = editFood.FoodName;
                EditCalories.Text = editFood.Calories.ToString();
                EditNotes.Text = editFood.Notes;
            }
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(Food))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetFood(int id)
    {
        Food food = db.Foods.Find(id);
        if (food == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(food);
    }



public partial class Food
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Food()
    {
        this.MealFoods = new HashSet<MealFood>();
    }

    public int FoodID { get; set; }
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
    public int Calories { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MealFood> MealFoods { get; set; }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aHIP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7sRu.png

Comment: Is it giving any extra information on 500 exception while you are debugging?

Comment: No nothing. I had this issue prior and was told to make a pseudo class to get around an error that was about getting all the foods from the database, but at that time I could not even connect to the database. At this point I can, but it is returning a 500 even though it has the information.

Comment: looks you calling this api from asp.net page. Can you try calling this directly from browser/fiddler like : http://localhost:63591/api/foods ? id=123

Comment: I mean, I can but it will not display anything since I am trying to display it on the asp.net.

Comment: I am not sure if I am following. All it says is, This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. https://i.imgur.com/A5cQwcS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead work directly with db.Foods, it's better to create your own public object and manage your query with Linq or if you persist to work directly with the object created by EntityFramework you must disable lazy-loading and proxy generation. 
Using your own implementation, the method should be like this:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(PseudoFood))]
public IHttpActionResult GetFood(int id)
{
    //Food food = db.Foods.Find(id);
    PseudoFood food = (from a in db.Foods
                       where a.FoodID == id
                       select new PseudoFood()
                       {
                           FoodName = a.FoodName,
                           FoodID = a.FoodID,
                           Calories = a.Calories,
                           Notes = a.Notes
                       }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (food == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(food);
}
```

Attention for the [ResponseType(typeof(PseudoFood))], that use PseudoFood instead Food.

Answer (score 1):

In the action `GetFood` you specified that the return type is `Food`. By default the EntityFramework generate proxy objects around your entities for lazy-loading.

Meaning that the line:

```
 Food food = db.Foods.Find(id);
```

Will not return a `Food` object, but a dynamic subclass of food. This can also be seen in the error you posted in the comments, stating that the action is not expecting type `Food_31C9E7DC...` to be returned.

---

There are 3 ways to fix this:

- Simply disable proxy generation in your EntityContext,
- Remove virtual properties (lazy-loading properties) on your entity (EF will skip proxy generation if its not needed),
- Map your EntityObject into a DataContract object and return it.

[See here for more info on proxies.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592886(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: I tried disabling the proxy and removing the virtual and did not help. I decided to go back and remove my custom poco class and for when I am retrieving all the foods originally and I get a stackoverflowexception.

Comment: @JonWisniewski did you disable the proxy generation from within the constructor of your EntityContext? A stackoverflow could happen if your serializer is going through navigation properties that have a circular reference.

Comment: I am using a junction table for food and meals called MealFood. Yes, I did disable it within constructor.

Comment: I was told since Food have MealFood and the MealFood have a reference back to Food, it cannot be serialized.

Comment: @JonWisniewski strange that it is still creating proxies, according to the documentation it shouldn't. You could remove the `ResponseType` attribute, disabling the validation on type. That should prevent it throwing an exception, but you'll probably still get a stackoverflowexception, as it most likely contain a circular reference. As for the serialization, it can be serialized, just not with default settings (or with all of them). You'll need to check if you can instruct the serializer to ignore your navigation properties.

Comment: @JonWisniewski did you find a solution for your problem? I'm experiencing the same here. Please share your solutions.